# Python how to define type hint for union of all subclasses

Tags: python, union, subclass, typing

Let's say I have a class that have multiple subclasses in a recursive/tree hierarchy:

```py
class Animal:
    pass
class Cat(Animal):
    pass
class HouseCat(Cat):
    pass
```

And I have a function, that can create instances of these classes based on some condition:

```py
from typing import Union
def creator(condition) -> Union[Animal, Cat, HouseCat]:
    # for codition1
    return Animal()
    # for codition2
    return Cat()
    # ...etc...
```

My problem is that PyCharm shows a warning for something like this, if I only use `-> Animal:` as return value annotation:

```py
my_list: List[Cat] = []
obj = creator(...)
my_list.append(obj)  # <-- Expected type 'Cat' (matched generic type '_T'), got 'Animal' instead
```

Is there a way to define a type hint instead of manually writing a `Union` for all subclasses?

Comment: `-> Animal` as subclasses will type correctly

Comment: `Type[Animal]` will do it :)

Comment: Sorry, edited the question, added my problem in PyCharm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `TypeVar` construct to write code with bounds:

```
from typing import TypeVar, List


class Animal:
    pass


class Cat(Animal):
    pass


class HouseCat(Cat):
    pass


A = TypeVar('A', bound=Animal)


def creator() -> A:
    pass


my_list: List[Cat] = []
obj = creator()
my_list.append(obj)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar